# Assigning an int value to a combo box when a row is selected from a tableview

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, tableview

I want to assign the particular material Id to the combo box once I click on a row in Table view.

```
void FictionSection::on_tblFiction_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
   int indicator = ui->tblFiction->model()->data(index).toInt();

    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare(" select fic_bk_id,material_id,no_of_cpy,shelf_num,edition from fiction "
                  "where material_id= :id or no_of_cpy=:copy or shelf_num=:shelf or edition=:edition");
    query.bindValue(":id",indicator);
    query.bindValue(":copy",indicator);
    query.bindValue(":shelf",indicator);
    query.bindValue(":edition",indicator);

    //Assigning table values to fields
    if(query.exec())
    {
        while(query.next())
        {
            ui->lneditMngFicId->setText(query.value(0).toString());
             ui->cmboxMngId->setCurrentText(query.value(1).toString());

            ui->lneditMngCpy->setText(query.value(2).toString());
            ui->spinbxMngShlf->setValue(query.value(3).toInt());
            ui->spinbxMngEdtn->setValue(query.value(4).toInt());

        }

    }
    else
    {
         QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Error","Couldn't load the values");
    }
}
```

Although other fields get the values once I click on any row combo box do not get the required value. material_id is stored as an int in database. I tried a lot to solve this.Please help me to solve this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because of the space in your query related to material_id:

```
material_id= :id
```

Comment: Have you verified the query does what you expect it to do? - ie are you sure you get a valid int back in material_id?

Comment: Other Qt things to verify (following the docs for QComboBox::currentText): "If the combo box is editable, the current text is the value displayed by the line edit. Otherwise, it is the value of the current item or an empty string if the combo box is empty or no current item is set." Is the box editable? If not, then I think you need to fill it first then setCurrentIndex(int index)